# Please help: Infinity: Indeterminate expression 0.0389874+Complexinfinity+Complexinfinity encountered

Tags: differential-equations

I'd like to solve the following second order differential equation:

$$\small \begin{pmatrix}M+m\sin^2\theta&m\sin\theta\cos\theta\\-m\sin\theta\cos\theta&-M-m\cos^2\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x}_M\\\ddot{h}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}m(g\cos\theta+r\dot{\theta}^2)\sin\theta-Ch\dot{x}_M\\\rho g A h-M g-m(g\cos\theta+r\dot{\theta}^2)\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

which I'd like to draw a graph of $x_M$ and $h$. $m$, $g$, and $M$ are real constants. $Cd$ is a well-defined function that has a parameter as $\dot{x}_M$,
$\theta$ is a piecewise defined function, that appears as below:

[image: plot]

for this equation, I used code :

```
\[Theta]0 = 0.5236; 
\[Omega]1 = 5.2359877; 
\[Omega]2 = 1.396;
t1 = \[Theta]0 / \[Omega]1;
t2 = \[Theta]0 / \[Omega]2;
T=2*(t1+t2);
f[t_]=Piecewise[{{ -Mod[t,T]*\[Omega]1 ,0<=Mod[t,T]<t1},{ -\[Theta]0+((Mod[t,T]-t1)*\[Omega]2), t1<=Mod[t,T]<(t1+2t2)},{\[Theta]0-((Mod[t,T]-t1-2t2)*\[Omega]1),(t1+2t2)<=Mod[t,T]<T}}]
```

[image: screenshot]

It is clear that derivative of the function is

```
thetaprime[t_]:=Piecewise[{{-5.2359877 ,0<=Mod[t,T]<t1},{ 1.396, t1<=Mod[t,T]<(t1+2t2)},{-5.2359877,(t1+2t2)<=Mod[t,T]<=T}}];
```

[image: screenshot]

for differential equation, I used a code

```
initconds = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0.00001, h[0] == (M + m)/(\[Rho]*A), h'[0] == 0}
eqns = {m Cos[\[Theta][t]] Sin[\[Theta][t]] h''[t] + (M + m (Sin[\[Theta][t]]^2)) x''[t] == - Cd[Derivative[1][x][t]] *h[t]* Derivative[1][x][t] + m Sin[\[Theta][t]] (g Cos[\[Theta][t]] + r thetaprime[t]^2),( -M-(m*Cos[\[Theta][t]]^2))*h''[t] - m Cos[\[Theta][t]] Sin[\[Theta][t]] x''[t] == -g M + A g \[Rho] h[t] - m Cos[\[Theta][t]] (g Cos[\[Theta][t]] + r thetaprime[t]^2)}
```

[image: screenshot]

But when I try to solve the Equation,

```
sol = NDSolve[Append[eqns, initconds], {x, h}, {t, 0, tf}, Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
```

[image: screenshot]

It gives following three errors. I can't understand why these errors occur.

```
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0.0389874 +ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered.

Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression -0.160636+ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered. 

NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0..
```

[image: screenshot]

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: In the equations you treat `θ[t]`as a function. Therefore you have 3 functions and you need 3 equations and not only 2.

Comment: Hmm,,, But I already defined θ[t] above the equation. Also, Error don't asked me to put more eqaations.

Comment: i can't see where you defined  `θ[t]`.  It is not the same as θ0